# Emitir mensaje al pulsar boton submit y mostrar resultado de acceso a bb.dd

Tags: entrada, onclick, submit, type

Tenemos una página con HTLM y codigo php con `include` (Busconv.php), en el que realizo una búsqueda en la bb.ddd, quisiera saber como puedo emitir un mensaje al  pulsar el botón BUSCAR y no exista registro en la bb.dd..

El planteamiento es:

Al acceder a la página se cargan 2 Select con el contenido de dos tablas de la bb.dd y nada más. y no de ningún mensaje de si existe o no en la busqueda de información.

Después,   se seleccione de ambos y se realice una búsqueda.

Si existen datos emite mensaje  `0-DATOS CORRECTOS DE LA INSCRIPCION DE ESTE SOCIO` y los muestra, esto es correcto.

Pero si no existen, NO emite  el mensaje de `3-NO EXISTE INSCRIPCION DE ESTE SOCIO` y solo quiero se muestre cuando se acceda y el resultado sea ese.

He resuelto el problema de  que  cuando nada mas abrir la pagina No me salta el mensaje.

Y lo que quisiera es que el mensaje me salga cuando pulse el boton y no existan datos.

Os informo del código:

```
<html>
<script language="JavaScript"> 
function pregunta(){ 
    if (confirm('Los datos serán guardados en la Base de Datos de SXXXX. ¿Estás seguro de realizar esta acción?')){ 
       document.Actualizar.submit() 
    } 
} 
</script> 
<body>
<h2 style="text-align: center; text-none: 6px 8px 10px #00FF00; text-decoration: underline; color: blue; font-size: 18pt; font-family: tahoma;"><b>MANTENIMIENTO DATOS INSCRIPCIONES</b> </h2>                                                            
<div  class="form-inline"> </body>
<form action=" " method="POST"> 
<?php
include("conexion.php");
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Error de Conexion/Fallida: " . $con->connect_error);
} 

$Var1='N';
$codigo_ruta=$_POST['numconv'];
$tildes = $con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
$sqlSocios = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Maesocios where situac ='A'
                                      ORDER BY nombre ");                                                                                                                                                    
mysqli_data_seek ($sqlSocios, 0);  

$sqlRutas = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Rutas
                                      ORDER BY fecha_programa desc");                                                                                                                                                    
mysqli_data_seek ($sqlRutas, 0);  ?>
<span style="color: red;" style="color: red;"> <strong> DNI SOCIO: <select name="dni"  style="width:300px" SIZE="0" autofocus> 
           <option value="">  Seleccionar  </option>" 
           <?
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlSocios)) {
             if(isset($_POST["dni"]) && $_POST["dni"]==$row['dni'])
              echo "<option value='".$row['dni']."'  selected >".$row['dni']." ".$row['nombre']." - ".$row['ape1']."</option>"; 
        else
            echo "<option value=".$row['dni'].">".$row['dni']." ".$row['nombre']." - ".$row['ape1']."</ - ".$row['ape1']."</option>"; } ?>?>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</select> <span style="color: red;" style="color: red;"> <strong>CONVOCATORIA: <select name="numconv"  style="width:250px" SIZE="0" autofocus> 
     <option value="">  Seleccionar  </option>" 
<?
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlRutas)) {
            if(isset($_POST["numconv"]) && $_POST["numconv"]==$row['codigo_ruta']) 
               echo "<option value='".$row['codigo_ruta']."'  selected >".$row['codigo_ruta']." ".$row['descripcion']."</option>";
            else
           echo "<option value=".$row['codigo_ruta'].">".$row['codigo_ruta']." ".$row['descripcion']."</option>"; } ?></select>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="BUSCAR" onclick= <?php include("BusConvo.php"); ?> >

<?php     if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {echo "<script> alert('0-DATOS CORRECTOS DE LA INSCRIPCION DE ESTE SOCIO');</script>";$Var1='S';} 
    else
       {if("$Var1"=='S')
             {;echo "<script> alert('3-NO EXISTE INSCRIPCION DE ESTE SOCIO');</script>";}
         else
             {$Var1='S';}
       }?>

</form>
```

Comment: Tu código es confuso. Por ejemplo tienes tu variable de control `$Var1` que seteas al principio como "N" y luego no la cambias apropiadamente a "S" en tu código como para que entre a la validación que te muestra el mensaje que deseas. El otro problema que veo es que ejecutas un fetch_array de una variable `$result` que no existe anteriormente lo cual siempre llevará la validación a la parte del else y nunca mostrará el primer mensaje.

Comment: Además en la validación del `if("$Var1"=='S')` nota que tienes la variable `$Var1` comentada por lo que estarías comparando dos strings directamente en vez del valor contenido en la variable con respecto al caracter "S". Trata de corregir todo lo que te menciono y prueba nuevamente por favor

Comment: La variable $result es el valor de retorno del código  php "Busconvo.php".he eliminado la siguiente codificación : {if("$Var1"=='S')
             {;echo "<script> alert('3-NO EXISTE INSCRIPCION DE ESTE SOCIO');</script>";}
         else
             {$Var1='S';}                                                                                 por la siguiente :  
       {if(isset($_POST["Fnumconv"]) && $_POST["Fnumconv"]=="") 
          {$Var1='S';echo "<script> alert('3-NO EXISTE INSCRIPCION DE ESTE SOCIO');</script>";